# Why does returned object not get attributes & methods of the class after __new__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`Index` objects of `diskcahe` have the property `_cache` with `Cache` object inside it. `Cache` is created with few arguments from those in `Index`. Unfortunately, it can take into account not all arguments, that is necessary for me. I had two options: either editing the package that will decrease universality of my code or using the method `fromcache` wherein I can put `Cache` with necessary arguments. I chose the latter.

I would like to add some useful attributes & methods to an object from `Index.fromcache()`, & to make its type `GeoCache`. I made the next class for this aim:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import *
from collections.abc import *

import re

import geocoder
from geocoder.arcgis import ArcgisResult
from geocoder.yandex import YandexResult
from diskcache import Index, Cache

class GeoCache(Index):
    CYRILLIC_LETTERS_PATTERN = re.compile(r"[А-Яа-я]")
    
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return Index.fromcache(Cache(*args, **kwargs))
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.request_map = self.cache["request-address"]
        except KeyError:
            self.request_map = {}
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(self.request_map[key])
        except KeyError:
            query = self.getGeocodeData(key).current_result
            self.request_map[key] = query.address
            if query.address not in self.request_map.values():
                self[query.address] = query
            return query
    
    @classmethod
    def getGeocodeData(cls, address: str) -> geocoder.api.ArcgisQuery | geocoder.api.YandexQuery:
        n = 10

        def call() -> geocoder.api.ArcgisQuery | geocoder.api.YandexQuery:
            try:
                if "Russia" in address:
                    return geocoder.yandex(location=address, key=YANDEX_APIKEY, lang="en_RU")
                if re.search(cls.CYRILLIC_LETTERS_PATTERN, address):
                    return geocoder.yandex(location=address, key=YANDEX_APIKEY, lang="ru_RU")
                return geocoder.arcgis(location=address)
            except:
                raise Exception(address)

        for _ in range(n):
            response = call()
            if response.ok:
                return response
        raise Exception(f"I got error {n} times in row with {address}")
    
    def close(self) -> NoReturn:
        self.cache["request-address"] = self.request_map
        super().cache.close()
```

But it produces only `Index` object. For instance, calling `close` gives `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'close'`. Why does object not take class methods & attributes after `__new__`?

---

The example of using:

```
geocache = GeoCache(GEOCACHE_PATH, size_limit=10*(1<<30)) #Creates the cache in specified directory & with necessary size limit

geocache["п. Костино, Рыбновский р-н, Рязанская обл"] #Geocode a request, cache & return the result

geocache["п. Костино, Рыбновский р-н, Рязанская обл"] #Return the result from the cache

geocache.close() #Save map "request : real address" & close the cache
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'd like to monkey-patch (more or less) `Index`, so that `Index.fromcache()` returns a `GeoCache` object? Because that seems like a tricky thing to do (though duck typing should make it safe. Then again, you're overriding quite a few dunder methods, so I'm not sure how safe).

Comment: Perhaps should add another small(!) code block that shows how you actually want to use things, and what you expect the result is. That may be clearer than describing it.

Comment: Because your `__new__` returns an `Index` object, not a `GeoCache` object. And `Index` doesn't have a `.close` method. note also, since `__new__` doesn't return a `GeoCache` the `__init__` is not run automatically

Comment: @9769953 I have just added it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, I understand that `__new__` returns `Index` instance. I replaced this intentionally. But I misunderstand why it does not run `__init__` & so on. At which point do python objects get their attributes, methods, & the class properties?

Comment: `__init__` is run after `__new__` but *only if `__new__` returns an instance of `cls`* But `Index` objects are not an instance of `GeoCache`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you! Is there any ways to add attributes, methods, & the class properties after that forcefully, automatically & into the class block?

Comment: So, from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__): "If `__new__()` does not return an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.". You could manually invoke it

Comment: One super-hacky thing you could try is in  `GeoCache.__new__` is `instance = Index.fromcache(Cache(*args, **kwargs))` then `instance.__class__ = GeoCache` and finally `return instance`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem is fundamentally that your `GeoCache.__new__` doesn't return a `GeoCache` instance, it returns an `Index` instance.

```
geocache = GeoCache(GEOCACHE_PATH, size_limit=10*(1<<30))
print(isinstance(geocache, GeoCache)
```

will print `False`.

And of course, instances of parent classes do not have access to child-class namespaces. You wouldn't expect `index = Index(whatever)` to be able to access a method you only defined in a subclass, would you?

Furthermore, for the instance attributes, `__init__` is called only if `__new__` returns an instance of that class.

One hack you can do to work around this is just "fix" the type of your instance by changing to to `GeoCache`, so:

```
class GeoCache(Index):
    ...
    
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = Index.fromcache(Cache(*args, **kwargs))
        instance.__class__ = GeoCache
        return instance
```

Note, if `Index` is a built-in class or defined as a C-extension, then this probably won't work. If it is defined in python, then it could work.

Comment: Yes, this works the way I needed exactly. Thank you very much for the help & new knowledge! This package is written in pure Python as it is stated by the author, so there is no problems! At last, I can process almost a thousand of virus specimens from Russia, Ukraine & other parts of former Soviet Union. They all are signed in native languages &, what is sadder, with spelling mistakes